# Why does postman return the same object to me in my get request multiple times? Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postman

Why does postman return the same object to me in my get request multiple times?
In my OneToMany relation I have Fetch.Lazy, however when I make the request it returns the same object multiple times. Attached screenshot of the output.

[image]

**Documento.java**

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pais_id", nullable = false)
    private Pais pais;
```

**Pais.java**

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Documento> documento;
```

I'm just returning a country(PAIS)

Comment: Which has a document, the document has pais, which has a document, which has a pais, which has a document, which has a pais, which.... Well you probably get the drift. You have a bi-directional relationship the whole `Pais` will be serialized so including the set of `Documento` which each have a `Pais` again. I'm a bit surprised you don't actually get a stack overflow error instead.

Comment: Yeah i saw the error , and i got stackoverflow error. How could i fix it?